# Multires baked texture is overlapped at some parts

Tags: texture-baking, multiresolution

My Multires baked texture is overlapped at some parts so the work doesn't look good.

Is there any option to make the bake not spread? The UV map doesn't overlapp

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In bake settings set margin smaller:

[image]

Please note, that margin is created in purpose. Most engines generate mip-maps, so that this margin is important for low-scale versions of the texture. Without it, seems becomes visible

Comment: thanks! it speed up my work